# Classes in TestNg POM framework are not getting executed in Sequence

Tags: selenium, testng

I am creating Simple Page Object Model framework in Selenium Java.
One .java class is one scenario.
So if i write this in TestNg.xml it works fine for one scenario.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" name="Test Simple Suite" parallel="false">  
    <listeners>
     <listener class-name="com.proj.Listener.Listeners"></listener>
    </listeners>
  <test thread-count="1" name="Test Basic Scenario1" parallel="false">
    <classes>
      <class name="TC001_SampleCase"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->**
```

However, when i write second class, it also start the execution of the same. Expected is, it should execute in sequence. Following testNg executes both classed in parallel

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" name="Test Simple Suite" parallel="false">  
    <listeners>
     <listener class-name="com.proj.Listener.Listeners"></listener>
    </listeners>
  <test thread-count="1" name="Test Basic Scenario1" parallel="false">
    <classes>
      <class name="TC001_SampleCase"/>
      <class name="TC002_SampleCase"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->**
```

**Would be really helpful, if anyone from the community can help on this issue. Thanks!**
Also note, in both classes i have given priorities to @Test.
TC001_SampleCase consists 20 @Test given Priority from 1 to 20
TC002_SampleCase consists 15 @Test given Priority from 21 to 35
TestNg version: 7.3
Selenium version: 3.141.59

Comment: How do you run your tests?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the Parallel Tag from Suite line. Just keep as below and try.

```
<suite thread-count="1" name="Test Simple Suite">
```

Comment: Hi Ketan, did tried the same. Same result, execution happening in parallel.
Note: I don't even have before test or before suite method written anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To executed test cases sequentially using testng.xml files, please pass

`preserve-order="true"`

Comment: Thanks for Reply Sudheer, but giving false without double quotes gives an error in testNg.xml
"open quote is expected for attribute "parallel" associated with an element type "suite".

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it ones if it works or not.

Comment: Hello Sudheer, made the change but still issue persists. 
Update TestNg.xml

<suite thread-count="1" name="Test Simple Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true"> 
 
 <listeners>
  <listener class-name="com.proj.Listener.Listeners"></listener>
 </listeners>
 
  <test thread-count="1" name="Test Basic Scenario1" preserve-order="true">
    
    <classes>
      <class name="TC001_SampleCase"/>
      <class name="TC002_SampleCase"/>
           
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: Try one more changes, give priority from 0 to N in every class, right now you have given priority from 1 to 20 for the 1st class and 21 to 35 for the second class.